# Is it true that $(f\cdot g)\circ \phi=(f\circ \phi)\cdot(g\circ \phi)$?

Tags: functions

Let be $f,g,\phi: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Is it true that $(f\cdot g)\circ \phi=(f\circ \phi)\cdot(g\circ \phi)$?

($\cdot$ is the product of functions)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common tool to use in this case is to consider what happens for a specific point:

Remember that $(f\cdot g)(x) := f(x)\cdot g(x)$

and that $(f\circ \phi)(x) := f(\phi(x))$

> Combine these pieces of information to get: $((f\cdot g)\circ\phi)(x) = (f\cdot g)(\phi(x)) = f(\phi(x))\cdot g(\phi(x))=\cdots$

If for every point in the domain it turns out that the two functions applied to that point are equal, then the two functions are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use the definition of the composition and the product of functions.